# Gson Parsing same key with different data

Tags: android, gson

How could I parse data received by server that contains different values for a key ?

```
{ "location":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}]}
```

and

```
{"location":{"id":"1"}}
```

Do not know for sure how to handle the following object :

```
   public class UserLocation {
    @SerializedName("location")
    List<String> location; / String location;

   @SerializedName("name")
    String name;
}
```

In a first request, I do get the array format and in a second request I do get string format from the server.

Comment: you need to create a custom deserializer for this object, and inside it - check if it's value is an object, or an array

Comment: Alright, thanks @VladMatvienko, this will do the trick.

Comment: i think its not a right way to get different data format for  same request try to use same format for both request .

Comment: One doubt , if first one is array, why you are sending object for second? it should array of one object right ?

Comment: @Bunny this is what I do get from the server, I do not have any access there.@Balu Sangem, correctly, this is how it should be , but as I've said , my access to server is none.

Comment: but you should not do it like that try to write less code as much you can this kind of writing code increases complexity of code and as well as effort to.talk to server side and convenience them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to use custom deserialization for that like this:

```
JsonDeserializer<UserLocation> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<UserLocation>() {
                @Override
                public UserLocation deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                    List<String> location  = new ArrayList<>();
                    if(json.isJsonArray()){
                        JsonArray jsonArray = json.getAsJsonArray();

                        for (JsonElement jsonElement : jsonArray) {
                            location.add(jsonElement.getAsString());
                        }

                    }else{
                        location.add(json.getAsString());
                    }
                    return  new UserLocation(location);
                }
            };

GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(UserLocation.class, deserializer);
Gson customGson = gsonBuilder.create();
UserLocation object = customGson.fromJson(jsoninput, UserLocation.class);
```

check this [link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-deserialization-basics) for more details

Answer (score -2):

Create one class which have both Location and Location List then Serialized that class object see below example.

**UserLocation.java**

```
public class UserLocation{

@SerializedName("location")
@Expose
private MyLocation myLocation;

}
```

**MyLocation.java**

```
public class MyLocation{


private List<Location> locationList = null;


private Location location;

}
```

**Location.java**

```
public class Location {

 @SerializedName("id")
 @Expose
 private String id;

 public String getId() {
 return id;
}

 public void setId(String id) {
 this.id = id;
}

 }
```