# How to populate this data in recyclerview adapter?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, pojo

I know how to work with this kind of response

```
[
        {
            “id": "1027",
            “name”: “abcd”,
            "age”: “30”
         },
        {
            “id”: "713",
            "name": "xyz”,
            “age”: “31”
        }
]
```

I do it like this:

```
Call<List<info>> call = apiInterface.getInfo(id);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<info>>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<info>> call, Response<List<info>> response) {

                    myList = response.body();
                    myAdapter = new coursesAdapter(myList, context);
                    recyclerview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<info>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

But This is the json response I am getting:

```
{
    "catalogue": [
        {
            “id": "1027",
            “name”: “abcd”,
            "age”: “30”
         },
        {
            “id”: "713",
            "name": "xyz”,
            “age”: “31”
        }
]
}
```

How can I populate this response in my recyclerview, or, how can I remove the catalogue and access the inner list directly for my recyclerview.

Any help will be greatly appreciated and acknowledged. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your adapter will remain the same. You just have to change the parsing logic.

```
Call<YourObj> call = apiInterface.getInfo(id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<YourObj>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<YourObj> call, Response<YourObj> response) {

            YourObj reponse = response.body();
            myAdapter = new coursesAdapter(reponse.info, context);
            recyclerview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<info>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Your Pojo class should look like this, make necessary changes to your pojo class as per your requirement.

```
public class Info {

    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;
    
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
    
    @SerializedName("age")
    public String age;

}


public class YourObj {

    @SerializedName("catalogue")
    public List<Info> info = null;
}
```

Comment: There is some problem in this, Call<YourObj> call = apiInterface.getInfo(id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<YourObj>() { I am not getting the response.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I was getting this java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference so I debugged and realised that the execution is coming out of the call method. I think there is something is wrong with this Call<YourObj> call

Comment: The json returns {
    "catalogue": false
} if  there is no data for an id. When i tried to pass that id, the same call function is giving this failure message java.lang.IllegalStateException:Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BOOLEAN at line 1 column 20 path $.catalogue

Comment: or there can be something wrong with the pojo class as well

Comment: If your catalogue sometimes returning a List and sometimes a boolean value then you need to have a dynamic parser for that. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48803808/gson-parsing-same-key-with-different-data